# How can I prevent scrolling to top of page when changing the height of a div within a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, height

I have a form with checkbox inputs that follow a certain hierarchy. I'm trying to make it so that clicking a button next to the input of a category toggles between showing and hiding the inputs of its subcategories. The toggling itself works just fine but it triggers a scroll to the top of the page. When I comment out the form tags the toggle works perfectly without the scrolling.

For reference, here's my html

```js
function showSubcategories(show_button) {
    let category_div = show_button.parentNode;
    let subcategories_divs = category_div.querySelectorAll('.subcategory');
    for (var i=0; i<subcategories_divs.length; i++) {
        subcategories_divs[i].style.height = "32px";
    }
    show_button.style.display = "none";
    category_div.querySelector('.hide-button').style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hideSubcategories(hide_button) {
    let category_div = hide_button.parentNode;
    let subcategories_divs = category_div.querySelectorAll('.subcategory');
    for (var i=0; i<subcategories_divs.length; i++) {
        subcategories_divs[i].style.height = "0px";
    }
    hide_button.style.display = "none";
    category_div.querySelector('.show-button').style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

```css
.subcategory {
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="category">
        <label for="category">category</label>
        <button class="show-button" onclick="showSubcategories(this)">&#8744</button>
        <button class="hide-button" onclick="hideSubcategories(this)">&#8743</button>
        <div class="subcategory">
            <input type="checkbox" value="subcategory1">
            <label for="subcategory1">subcategory1</label>    
        </div>
        <div class="subcategory">
            <input type="checkbox" value="subcategory2">
            <label for="subcategory2">subcategory2</label>    
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm altering the height of each individual subcategory input separately because there's a variable number of subcategories for each category. I've tried placing all the subcategories within a single div and changing that div's height but I get the same issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default type of a button is submit:

> type = submit|button|reset [CI]
>
> This attribute declares the type of the button. Possible values:
>
> submit: Creates a submit button. **This is the default value**.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

So you'd have to use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the submit, or specify `type="button"` for the buttons.

```js
function showSubcategories(show_button) {
    show_button.parentNode.classList.toggle("open", true);
}

function hideSubcategories(hide_button) {
    hide_button.parentNode.classList.toggle("open", false);
}
```

```css
.subcategory {
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
div.menu:not(.open) > .hide-button,
div.menu.open > .show-button
{
  display: none;
}
div.menu.open > .subcategory
{
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="menu">
        <input type="checkbox" value="category">
        <label for="category">category</label>
        <button class="show-button" type="button" onclick="showSubcategories(this)">&#8744</button>
        <button class="hide-button" type="button" onclick="hideSubcategories(this)">&#8743</button>
        <div class="subcategory">
            <input type="checkbox" value="subcategory1">
            <label for="subcategory1">subcategory1</label>    
        </div>
        <div class="subcategory">
            <input type="checkbox" value="subcategory2">
            <label for="subcategory2">subcategory2</label>    
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh god this is brilliant! Worked perfectly; thanks so much! Do you happen to know why it was triggering that submission?

Comment: Just did a littler research: for the most browsers the default type for `<button>` is `submit`, so a better solution is to actually specify `type="button"` (I've updated my answer)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! Cheers mate.